# Query additional table based on not null in table values and return to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I'm trying to write and application that stores recipes. However some ingredients can also be "recipes". What I am stuck on now is how do I present a full list of ingredients for something that has multiple possible different smaller recipes that make it up. Sorry this is a little long. Here is the models:

```
public class Recipe
{

    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public string Recipe_Name { get; set; }
    public int Labor_Cost { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RecipeDetail> RecipeDetails { get; set; }

}

public class RecipeDetail
{
    public int RecipeDetailID {get; set;}
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public int IngrediantID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingrediant Ingrediant { get; set; }

}

public class Ingrediant
{

    public int IngrediantID { get; set; }
    public string Ingrediant_Name { get; set; } 
    public bool? BreaksDown { get; set; }
    public int? RecipeID { get; set; }  

    public virtual AHItem AHItems { get; set; }

}
```

So here is what my thoughts have been and think it would work but i feel it is very in correct. My first idea was just to pass the entire linked Database to the view and then pull out what i needed from there.

So the controller would look something like this: (just sends everything to the view).

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    ViewBag.SelectedDetail = id;

    Recipe recipe = db.Recipes;
    if (recipe == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

        return View(recipe);
}
```

Then all the filtering would happen in the view... kind of like this (yes this is ugly and it creates the wrong table structure, i was going to fix it once i got it figured out).

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RecipeDetails)
{
    if (item.RecipeID == ViewBag.SelectedDetail)
    {
        if (item.Ingrediant.AHItems != null)
        {
            x = x + item.Ingrediant.AHItems.Cost;
        }
          <tr>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ingrediant.Ingrediant_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            </td>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ingrediant.AHItems.Cost)
            </td>
         </tr>

    if (item.Ingrediant.RecipeID != null)
    {
        y= item.Ingrediant.RecipeID;
        foreach (var i in Model.RecipeDetails)
        {
           if (item.RecipeID == y)
           {
             <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Amount Needed</th>
                <th>AH Cost</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Ingrediant.Ingrediant_Name)
               </td>
               <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Quantity)
               </td>
               <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Ingrediant.AHItems.Cost)
               </td>
             </tr>
            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So while I think i can make the above work it seems like it is a lot of extra work to be done in the view. How do i move this into the controller instead?

*P.S. Is there a way to see what the full linked table that the model will make looks like for the example above when "recipe" is passed to the view without having to code something to see it? I would like to see the joins (and how the query is written) so i can better understand what it is doing.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing all recipes to a view that's intended to display just one is not a good idea at all. Get just the recipe that you need:

```
var recipe = db.Recipes.Find(id);
if (recipe == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

However, since you have related entities that you'll also be utilizing in the view, you should modify that slightly to:

```
var recipe = db.Recipes.Include("RecipeDetail.Recipe").Include("RecipeDetail.Ingredient").SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
```

That will issue a join for `RecipeDetail` and also joins for the `Recipe` and/or `Ingredient` properties on `RecipeDetail`. The result will be a single `Recipe` instance the view needs based on the id which contains all the related `RecipeDetail` instances eagerly loaded along with the information from the `Recipe` or `Ingredient` related to each `RecipeDetail`. Your view now has all the information it needs in a single query, and you didn't have to dump the database to the view to do it.

Comment: Thats for the help I will give this a try. Before i was using the db.Recipes.Find(id) but then I would not get the entire RecipeDetail and Ingredient tables i needed to pull the information for the "smaller" recipes that made up the bigger recipes. I was only able to pull in what was related to the ID passed to the controller.

Comment: Yep this is the same problem as before.Using the above query the model is not bringing in the other 4 items in the table not directly related to the id value. I need to be able to bring those in as well since these values make up the other recipes that are making up the main recipe.

Comment: If you're talking about the related items on the recipes related to the main recipe, you would just need to extend the include to bring in more joins: `.Include("RecipeDetail.Recipe.RecipeDetail.Recipe")`, etc. However, that's going to make for a very large and probably slow query. In a scenario like yours, there's really no need to bring the details for a recipe being used as an ingredient. Simply make it a link that directs the user to the detail page for that recipe.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one of the main goals of this project is to calculate the overall price for a recipe while displaying all the ingredients and the additional ingredients that make up the recipe. Since the above would be slow would it make more sense to bring in full version of the ingredients table using a viewmodel and just query that?

Comment: For something like calculating the total price you should use a stored procedure. You could also use a stored procedure to collect all the ingredients. Entity Framework, or any ORM really, is an extremely bad choice for a recursive pull of unknown depth.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'll look into that more. I'm still pretty new.